# How can i parseFloat a php var inside javascript

Tags: php, javascript

I need to parseFloat this then to replace the dot with a comma:

```
sum="<?php echo substr($_tarif_membre,0,-2).'.'.substr($_tarif_membre,-2,2) ?>" *  $('#tarif_membre').val()
total_total= sum.replace('.',',')
$('#total_total').val(sum)
```

if i dont multiply the php echoed variable by `$('#tarif_membre').val()`  it will still show the result as a float:12.00 (as it is echoed from php)  but if i multiply by  `$('#tarif_membre').val()`  the result will show 12, why? and why does the replace method does not work(i need to show comma separated values)

Comment: what on earth are you trying to do with that code?

Comment: displaying monetary values that come from a mysql database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I *think* this is what you're trying to do:

```
var sum = 12.00 * parseFloat($('#tarif_membre').val());
total_total= sum.toFixed(2).replace('.',',');
$('#total_total').val(total_total);
```

[You can try it out here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/anQNn/).

You should leave off the quotes since it's a number, then [`parseFloat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Functions#parseInt_and_parseFloat_Functions) the `#tarif_membre` [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/), since that will be a string, then they key to mainain decimal places for money here is calling [`.toFixed()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) on that float, this will get you `"12.00"`, a string.  You can them replace the `.` for a `,` (for international formatting I'm guessing?)  Then I'm sticking that result into the `#total_total`, though this piece I'm unsure on.

For the other question, why doesn't [`.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) work?  It's because in your code it was a float, not a string, and only strings have the replace method.

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript, there's no difference between an integer and a float. `var x = 12.00` will, when converted back to string, just show "12".

If you want to show the number formatted, you either have to keep it as a string (`"12.00"`); or you need some code similar in behavior to `printf` (which Javascript doesn't have; but there are Javascript libraries available that implement it, for example [here](http://www.diveintojavascript.com/projects/javascript-sprintf)) to format it again with as many decimals as you like.